# allow specific role in cas

Tags: authentication, cas

I have a cas server that authenticate and send back some attributes corerectly. Now i want to add a service that check user roles in principal attributes and allow access to a service only if logged in user has the Specific role ( like admin role!).

I read about 'requiredHandlers' and thought it can help, but i can not make it work!

For service, i have something like this:

```
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
        <property name="id" value="1"/>
        <property name="name" value="Admin panel service"/>
        <property name="serviceId" value="http://localhost:8080/admin"/>
        <property name="evaluationOrder" value="0"/>
        <property name="ignoreAttributes" value="true"/>
        <property name="requiredHandlers" value="supporterAuthenticationHandler"> <!-- this is what i found so far -->
        </property>
    </bean>
```

where `supporterAuthenticationHandler` is defined in `authenticationManager`

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver"/>
            <entry key-ref="primaryAuthenticationHandler"><null /></entry>
            <entry key-ref="supporterAuthenticationHandler"><null /></entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>

    <property name="authenticationPolicy">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AnyAuthenticationPolicy"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And `supporterAuthenticationHandler` is a simple implemention of AuthenticationHandler (nothing implemented in it yet.

problem is i can not make cas to check `supporterAuthenticationHandler` so that i can go further (and probably fall into another hole where i need the new Principal with attributes).

Am i going completely the wrong way? Shall i check user role in my admin application? is it even possible to check roles with cas with different services?

Answer (score 0):

This goes to the point that CAS is an authentication service not an authorization service. CAS only ensures that users are who they say they are not what they can do in an application (service).

please see this answer

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/can-central-authentication-service-cas-do-authorization

Comment: I don`t want to use cas as authorization. well. It is a bit authorization, but i want to do it for the whole service, not only a part of it. I already read about it somewhere, but was unable to find it again. CAS must be able to authorize access to an special service somehow. (right now i check service authorization in side the service)

Comment: Based on your question it is authorization. Authentication only confirms who the user is not what role they have in your security system. You would have to build an entire authorization system in cas to do what you want. Why go through the trouble when there are already systems out there that do authorization and authentication.